# How do I make my modal window only show up once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, modal-dialog

How would I add a cookie attachment to the script? I have looked through this website, tried to place the codes but nothing ever worked.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

//select all the a tag with name equal to modal
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

});

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask, .window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
```

Anyone that can help me add a cookie segment so the window only opens once/user would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the event on `click` only once with `one()`:

```
$('a[name=modal]').one('click', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants, given the mention of using a cookie. When the page is refreshed, the modal window will be openable again.

Comment: That's right but the question is a bit confusing, but this might help though, don't know..